# C# - find a line (regex) in a file and get the complete block of text according to another regex

Tags: c#, regex, search, find

The problem is this:

I want to find a regex in a textfile and get the complete block of text

Text example:

```
text text text text text text text text text 
!
title
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
!
text text text text text text text text text
```

finding the "title" part is easy but I want to get the following result:

```
title
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text 
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
```

What is the best way to go? Working with a regex pattern or selecting the text until I get a "!"? (I want to have simple/fast readable code)

Code for finding a pattern: (with rtxtText as the richtextbox)

```
    private String searchInfo(String pattern)
    {
        String text = rtxtText.Text;
        Regex regExp = new Regex(pattern);
        String result = "";

        foreach (Match match in regExp.Matches(text))
        {
            result += "\n" + match.ToString();
        }
        return result; 
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Regex be changed to contain the unknown characters as well, like

- first `title`
- then `[^!]*` (`[^ ]` means something not in this set, so `[^!]*` is everything except `!` in any number)

  Regex regex = new Regex("title[^!]*", RegexOptions.SingleLine);
  MatcheCollection matches = regex.Matches(text);

Comment: the following use of regex solved my problem: 

searchInfo(@"\ntitle[^!]*")

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. If you don't want the starting line break in your result, you should check out "lookbehind"'s: `searchInfo(@"(?<=\n)title[^!]*");`

Answer (score 1):

The best way is just to loop over the lines of text until you find the first '!' and then collect until you find the next:

```
line = textfile.readline()
while line and line.strip() != '!'
    line = textfile.readline() # skip until first '!'
title = textfile.readline() # now on title line
text = ''
line = textfile.readline()
while line and line.strip() != '!'
    text += line
    line = textfile.readline()
print title
print text
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is definately not the best way. He just hat to change his regex to find the text up to the ! as well.

Comment: @Hinek, you might be right - I'm not quite sure what OP wants. It just didn't look like a problem for regex to me...

Comment: I just read the question again, it is unclear. Maybe he just wants to isolate, what's between two exclamation marks, that are at the begin of the line. If this is the case I would agree with your answer. Let's just say it's his turn now to clarify ...

Comment: To clarify the question: I wanted to isolate the blocks beginning with "title" and ending with "!". This is commonly used in config-files. To give some context: my purpose is to analyse config files based on blocks present in this config file. I'm searching for "title1" and want to know "parameter1" present in this block. To do so, I need to isolate this block base on the beginnen parameter "title" and the ending parameter "!". I want to thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
public IEnumerable<string> ParseParagraphs(string text)
{
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"title[^!]*");
    foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(text))
        yield return match.Value;  
}
```

Usage is simple:

```
foreach (var p in ParseParagraphs(your_text))
    Console.WriteLine(p);
```

UPDATE: Use StringBuilder in your SearchInfo method to avoid creating many strings in memory

```
private string SearchInfo(String pattern)
{            
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(rtxtText.Text, pattern);
    if (matches.Count == 0)
        return String.Empty;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Match match in matches)
        sb.AppendLine(match.Value);

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

And call it this way `var result = SearchInfo(@"title[^!]*");`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this helped me with improving my code!